# Kafka - which kafka version I should start with

Tags: apache-kafka

I wanted to get started with kafka ( i had little experience with kafka 0.10 , and now, it seems there are "major" changes happened) 
I am going through release changes of kafk. However, I am stuck with which version I should choose in terms of stability , community support . I am little reluctant to use the latest version 2.5

Please suggest me a version which didn't get a lot of "major" changes . I heard kafka 2.1 is good start as it had some breaking changes from previous version .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're making the leap from 0.10, I don't see any point in stopping part-way with 2.1. 
In terms of releases, the latest stable release is 2.5.0. If you prefer, 2.4 was released in December 2019 and has had a dot release since (2.4.1).

Check out this [excellent talk](https://kafka-summit.org/sessions/please-upgrade-apache-kafka-now/) which addresses why you should upgrade.

---

> I didn't find a lot of material about 2.5

The majority of material is version agnostic (unless it's based on super-old versions, like 0.10 etc). If you want to see breaking changes specifically, [look at the download page](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads) which notes major changes and links to the release notes for each version which lists every single change.

Comment: right, but, I didnt find a  lot of material about 2.5 , However, there are a lot for 2.0 and 2.1 such kafka definitve guide etc.. those provide concise details - which was the primary reason of me asking this question - is it ok to start with 2.1 so that I wont hit with lot of major changes

Comment: @Nag, not sure why you would look at something else but the latest version. You have documentation from Apache, Confluent and access to full source code. The definitive guide book is still useful as concepts did not really change since its release.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Mike is also correct in the points that he makes.

Comment: You can also always use ACC (https://lvc.github.io/japi-compliance-checker/) to check version compatibility.